# Exclude some characters from a Lex regex

Tags: html, regex, markdown, lex

I am trying to build a regex for lex that match the bold text in mardown syntax. For example: `__strong text__` I thought this:

```
__[A-Za-z0-9_ ]+__
```

And then replace the text by

```
<strong>Matched text</strong>
```

But in Lex, this rule causes the variable `yytext` to be `__Matched Text__`. How could I get rid of the underscores? It would be better to create a regex that does not match the underscores or proccess the variable `yytext` to remove it?

With capturing groups it would be easer, because I would only need the regex:

```
__([A-z0-9 ]+)__
```

And use `\1`. But Lex does not support capturing groups.

### Answer

I finally take the first option offer by João Neto, but a little modified:

```
yytext[strlen(yytext)-len]='\0'; // exclude last len characters
yytext+=len; // exclude first len characters
```

I've tried with `Start conditions` as he mentioned as second option, but did not work.

Comment: Can you perform another search for `[A-z0-9 ]+` on `yytext`?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R I think not, but do not know, I am new to Lex. As far as I've searched, it is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can process `yytext` by removing the first and last two characters.

```
yytext[strlen(yytext)-2]='\0'; // exclude last two characters
yylval.str = &yytext[2]; // exclude first two characters
```

Another option is to use stack

```
%option stack
%x bold

%%

"__"         { yy_push_state(bold); yylval.str = new std::string(); }
<bold>"__"   { yy_pop_state(); return BOLD_TOKEN; }
<bold>.|\n   { yylval.str += yytext; }
```

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the answer with what I did to solve it